# How to submit URL of official website of topic using Freebase Loader (or other ways to import)?

Tags: url, freebase

Is it possible to submit URLs of websites of topics using [Freebase Loader](http://data.labs.freebase.com/loader/)?

For example, I want to upload organizations with URLs of their websites:

```
/type/object/name   (what_here?)    /type/object/type   /organization/organization/organization_type
The Forum for Collaborative HIV Research    http://www.hivforum.org/    /organization/organization  /en/aids_service_organization
The Elizabeth Glaser Pediatric AIDS Foundation  http://www.pedaids.org/ /organization/organization  /en/aids_service_organization
```

What identifier should be on column with URLs? Or it is not possible at all?

If loading website URLs with Freebase Loader is not possible, what is preferred way to do this? Loading with Refine is unacceptable - it [requires 8 users to approve each triple](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Refinery), resulting in never imported datasets. And my dataset here is small, only 12 organizations. Is there any way for quick imports of small datasets containing URLs?

Answer (score 0):

For 12 URLs, the simplest thing to do is just go to the 12 pages and add them, assuming they don't exist already.  The Elizabeth Glaser foundation, for example, has had the URL [listed](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/elizabeth_glaser_pediatric_aids_foundation) for over a year.